# fillter and get all the values greater than current date

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to filter and get all the values greater than current date.
I researched about it, but couldn't able to figure out what is wrong in my code.

below is models.py

```
class TrainingDetails(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    trainer_name = models.ManyToManyField(TrainerDetails, blank=True, 
    related_name='trainer',default='')
    tutorial_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    agenda = models.FileField(upload_to='media')
    from_time = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingDate,blank=True, related_name='from_times', 
    default='')
    trainingdate = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingDate,blank=True, related_name='dates', 
    default='')
    to_time = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingDate,blank=True, related_name='to_times', 
    default='')
    url = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingData, blank=True, related_name='links', default='')
    document = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingData, blank=True, related_name='files' 
    ,default='')
    tutorial_name = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingData, blank=True, related_name='tut_name' 
    ,default='')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "TrainingDetails"
```

views.py

```
class TrainingDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = TrainingDetails.objects.all().order_by('code')
    serializer_class = TrainingDetailsSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        today = datetime.date.today()
        trainingdate = TrainingDate.objects.values('trainingdate')
        query_set = queryset.filter(trainingdate__gte = today)
        return query_set
```

Error Message i got,

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.date(2020, 10, 29)
```

Comment: What is not working? What error message do you get?

Comment: added error message in edit

Answer (score 0):

try to change TrainingDate to TrainingDetails in queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        today = datetime.date.today()
        trainingdate = TrainingDetails.objects.values('trainingdate')
        query_set = queryset.filter(trainingdate__gte = today)
        return query_set
```